# Docker install in Ubuntu trusty

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

Trying to install Docker in Ubuntu trusty following instructions here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Tried first to use repo. That failed with

```
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
```

Next, tried to download .deb file, but I could not find it at

https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/stable/

Finally tried get-docker.sh script, that failed with:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease Unable to find expected entry ‘edge/binary-i386/Packages’ in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

How can I do this install? This should not be so hard, so it’s probably me, but I don’t know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit system? Docker needs a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Yes, I am running 32 bit. I will see if I can upgrade. I am running Ubuntu in vagrant/virtualbox running on Windows Server 2016 running in VMware on a 64 bit Mac.I am trying to emulate a production environment. I did install the 64 bit vagrant, not sure why I get the 32 Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Installed 64 bit OS and then I was able to install docker.